# What is the benefit of string formatting in python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

What are some examples of when string formatting is beneficial? I understand how to implement string formatting operations, but I am not sure of how they are helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String formatting is helpful because it allows us to make a template, and then fill in the details when we have them.

Without these types of features we would be constructing strings dynamically with `''.join()` or `+` which is messy and/or error prone.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
print("%d %-10s %.02f" % (a, b, c))
```

Is better than:

```
print(str(a) + " " + b + " " * (10 - len(b)) + " " + str(round(c, 2)))
```

Being `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
a = 1
b = "Dog"
c = 5.668451
```

Also is very useful when developing a multi-language software.

Comment: The example is good, the motivation is pretty weak. Fix it and you'll get my upvote!

Comment: Look at the code for the motivation :lol:. Sorry, my English is very poor, can't explain too much :-(.